# Confused on what steps make this equality

Tags: algebraic-equations

The solutions manual gives this equality without an explanation (as usual); I've been stuck at this for a good while and don't feel like wasting any more time
$$\frac{(n+1)^2}{2^{n+1}}\times\frac{2^n}{n^2}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\times\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Hint: $\;2^{n+1} = 2 \cdot 2^n\,$ and $\,\frac{n+1}{n} = \frac{n}{n} + \frac{1}{n}\,$.

Comment: Why is this tagged with [inequality]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{(n+1)^2}{2^{n+1}}\times\frac{2^n}{n^2}&=\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{(n+1)^2}{2^n}\times\frac{2^n}{n^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\times\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^2\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\times\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2
\end{align*}